# Does Java mail work differently on different operating system

Tags: java, email, smtp, portability

- We are using 2 SMTP servers one that runs on Solaris 11 and other that
  runs on Win 2K8.
- And I'm compiling the codes using a PC that runs on Windows
  XP.
- The business code runs in server that runs on Solaris 11.

I'm forbidden to bring out the business code, its an enterprises application that sends approximately 1000 mails a day.

1. And the code gets a Socket object for the SMTP server and
2. Prints some protocol related messages like "MAIL FROM: mail_id@domain.tld"
   and flushes it.
3. then gets a input steam object of the socket and checks for error.

This way mails are sent. The problem is that, code that runs in windows PC using Windows SMTP is not running for Solaris SMTP. Why JAVA, which is advocate to be platform portable is behaving like this? **Java version is 1.3.2**

```
     Socket socketSMTP= new Socket(server_name,smtp_port);
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(socketSMTP.getInputStream()));
     PrintWriter writer= new PrintWriter(socketSMTP.getOutputStream());
     String respones="";
     //--Some codes to check if server is ready --
     writer.println("MAIL FROM:<"+sender_address.trim()+">");
     writer.flush();
     respones=reader.readLine();         
     if(!tmp_msg.startsWith("250"))throw new Exception("Error in protocol "+respones);
```

this part is where I'm getting error, Solaris SMTP expect 'username' in the place of sender_address whereas Windows SMTP expects 'mail id' in place of sender_address; sender_address is a String variable available from a POJO class

Comment: just add a small check , use the **GMail ports** and try on both servers , **IF works THEN** you got some kind of bug at sockets usage at one server , **why i said gmail is -> its a third party mail client\server and has such no bugs reported**

Comment: "is not running" is the worst possible description of an error. Are we supposed to have a crystal ball? And sounds like you are ignoring the Java Mail API, why deal with sockets?

Comment: If you're doing custom SMTP instead of Java mail, chances are your SMTP implementation is breaking due to differences in the Windows SMTP server and  Solaris SMTP servers.

Comment: SMTP servers differ (sometimes wildly) from one another, are you sure it is not a server issue?

Comment: @GyroGearless sadly I'm not the developer, its a decade old application that I'm trying to fix! neither I know why they'd want to do that. @ Ireeder @ nablex I haven't thought about this, error occurs with mail id, while it's flushed to socket's stream ... the same code picks username as mail id for Solaris SMTP and picks correctly for Windows SMTP but when I run from Solaris machine things get even messier.

Comment: But then it's impossible to help you without some code snippets, dump of the SMTP conversation, stack traces etc. As @nablex said, there are plenty of different mails servers with zillions of configuration options...

Comment: @GyroGearless I have edited the question, will this help? and the code is not using java mail api as you mentioned

Comment: I suspect your mail server wants an authorization. Maybe talk to your unix admin if he/she can disable that for your application. Otherwise you have to bite the dust and implement the missing parts of SMTP for your application. See the appendix of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smtp for a list of relevant RFCs...

Comment: Thanks for the inputs guys, hope I'd be able work with this and will update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it does work differently + different SMTP servers were installed. Solaris and Windows did not have same SMTP server (the software).

Now we use Windows SMTP I run it from any machine with windows os and vice versa